# All matches in a line : Spacy matcher

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am looking for a solution to print all the matching in a line using Spacy matcher

The example goes like this,
Here I am trying to extract experience.

```
doc = nlp("1+ years of experience in XX, 2 years of experiance in YY")
pattern = [{'POS': 'NUM'}, {'ORTH': '+', "OP": "?"}, {"LOWER": {"REGEX": "years?|months?"}}]
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("Skills", None, pattern)
matches = matcher(doc)
pirnt(doc[matches[0][1]:matches[0][2]]
```

Here I am getting output `1+ years`.

But I am looking for a solution having output
`['1+ years','2 years']`

Comment: It looks like this code returns `2 years` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the first item as `'LIKE_NUM': True`:

```
pattern = [{'LIKE_NUM': True}, {'ORTH': '+', "OP": "?"}, {"LOWER": {"REGEX": "(?:year|month)s?"}}]
```

I also contracted the `years?|months?` to `(?:year|month)s?`, you might even consider matching full token string using `^(?:year|month)s?$`, but that is not necessary at this point.

Code:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{'LIKE_NUM': True}, {'ORTH': '+', "OP": "?"}, {"LOWER": {"REGEX": "(?:year|month)s?"}}]
matcher.add("Skills", None, pattern)

doc = nlp("1+ years of experience in XX, 2 years of experiance in YY")

matches = matcher(doc)
for _, start, end in matches:
  print(doc[start:end].text)
```

Output:

```
1+ years
2 years
```

Comment: The contraction breaks the 1+ (it is matchet twice). Keep the original {"LOWER": {"REGEX": "years?|months?"}} and it works. The problem seems to lie in POS Tagger for the first value as Num. Keep in mind that it may work if the phrase starts otherwise.

Comment: @TiagoDuque I get `1+ years` and `2 years` only, the `(?:year|month)s?` and `years?|months?` are equivalent. `1` is `X`, not `num`, that is why it was not matched.

Comment: I guess it has to do with the "lower". Now that you corrected it, its working here.